# Palindrome Recursion Not Stopping

Tags: c++, recursion, palindrome

I've built the framework but I'm running into a logic error that I can't catch. To summarize what it does it passes a string to the book function and checks the first and last chars and if there are the same continues to do so until there is a char left. If the letters aren't the same it just returns false. However, the results are bugged when a valid palindrome is entered it gets to the base case but doesn't stop the recursion and ends up returning 0 when it is, in fact, a palindrome. Any insight as to why it's not stopping would be great!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

bool book(string origWord, int len);



int main()
{
    string a = "ABCDCBA";
    cout << "Test:" << book(a, a.length() - 1);
    return 0;
}
bool book(string origWord, int len)
{
    bool status = false;
    if (len <= 1)
    {
        status = true;
    }
    else if (tolower(origWord[0]) == tolower(origWord[len]))
    {
        book(origWord.substr(1, len - 1), len - 2);
    }

    return status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (tolower(origWord[0]) == tolower(origWord[len]))
{
    book(origWord.substr(1, len - 1), len - 2);
}
```

Here you throw away the value returned from book. You probably want this instead:

```
status = book(origWord.substr(1, len - 1), len - 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how control may flow through this function:

```
bool book(string origWord, int len)
{
    bool status = false;  // 1. status is FALSE
    if (len <= 1)  // 2. This branch is not taken
    {
        status = true;
    }
    else if (tolower(origWord[0]) == tolower(origWord[len]))  // 3. This branch IS taken
    {
        book(origWord.substr(1, len - 1), len - 2);  // 4. Say, this returns TRUE
        // 5. but the return value is not used
    }
    // 6. control passes here after executing the function
    // 7. local status is STILL FALSE
    return status;  // 8. return status, which is FALSE 
}
```

How to solve:

```
bool book(string origWord, int len)
{
    if (len <= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (tolower(origWord[0]) == tolower(origWord[len]))
    {
        // Use the RETURNED VALUE!
        return book(origWord.substr(1, len - 1), len - 2);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool book(string origWord, int start, int len);



int main()
{
    string a = "ABCDCBA";
    if(book(a, 0, a.size() - 1)) {
        cout << "Palindrome \n";
    } else {
        cout << "Not Palindrome \n";
    }

    return 0;
}
bool book(string origWord, int start, int len)
{
    if(origWord[start] != origWord[len]) {
        return false;
    }
    if(start == origWord.size() - 1) {
        return true;
    }
    return book(origWord, ++start, --len);
}
```

I add a start point in function call.